# “Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy” Between Subdomains in JS?

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, tumblr, policy, getimagedata

I have a Tumblr theme that includes a `canvas` script.
The Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy doesn't allow `context.getImageData()` to work.   Script is located at **user.tumblr.com**,
images are located at **static.tumblr.com**.

Is there any solution for this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[document.domain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.domain) will be your friend there.

I haven't studied the canvas security model closely, but if it follows the rest of Javascript, setting

```
document.domain = tumblr.com
```

might help.

(Googling for document.domain canvas may lead to more.)

Comment: The last sentence is a bit too general. Have you tried it and found something valuable?

Comment: Can't say I have -- I don't use canvas much.  However, I figured that giving a couple of key phrases might let the OP explore options.